# why is custom routedevent not handled in my xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a WPF MainWindow with my own RoutedEvent, which is raised when pushing the Enter key.

```
namespace ZK16
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public static readonly RoutedEvent CustomEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "Custom", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MainWindow));

    public event RoutedEventHandler Custom
    {
        add { AddHandler(CustomEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(CustomEvent, value); }
    }

    void RaiseCustomEvent()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("RaiseCustomEvent");
        RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(MainWindow.CustomEvent);
        RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AddHandler(MainWindow.CustomEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(MyCustomHandler));
    }

    private void MyCustomHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("In Eventhandler...");
    }

    private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            RaiseCustomEvent();
    }
```

In XAML I add a Label with an EventTrigger,

```
<Window x:Class="ZK16.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ZK16"
    Title="MainWindow"
    PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown"
    >
<Grid>
    <Label Content="Hello World">
        <Label.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:MainWindow.Custom">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Duration="00:00:1">
                        <DoubleAnimation From="6" To="25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Label.Triggers>
    </Label>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

but when raising the custom event,
the EventTrigger does not fire on my event, but fires if e.g.

```
EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded"
```

Can anybody tell me, what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a minunderstanding of what a routed event is.

This [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms742806(v=vs.100).aspx) states the following:

> **Bubbling**: Event handlers on the **event source** are invoked. The routed event then **routes to successive parent elements** until reaching the element tree root...
>
> **Tunneling**: Initially, **event handlers at the element tree root are invoked**. The routed event then **travels a route through successive child elements** along the route, towards the node element that is the routed event source (the element that raised the routed event)...

In your case you have a bubbling event. You raise it in the `MainWindow` (the source) so it will start going from that element upwards. Nothing is above `MainWindow` so it stops there.

If you change your event to a tunneling event this would happen. You raise it from `MainWindow` (the source) so the event starts travelling from the parents to the source, again, nothing is above `MainWindow`, same result.

Now if you do the following in your XAML:

```
<Label x:Name="MyLabel" Content="Hello World">
```

And this in your code:

```
MyLabel.RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
```

The route will be the following in a bubbling event's case:

`Label` (source) -> `Grid` -> `MainWindow`

And in a tunneling event's case:

`MainWindow` -> `Grid` -> `Label` (source)

This person had the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336140/handle-tunneled-custom-routed-event).

Comment: Great answer! Thanksalot